# Bootstrap Table class Overriding style of react-datetime in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having a calendar inside a table in a react functional component ,

```
 <table className="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
       // some code
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <DatePickerComponent
      date={value}
      dateFormat={"DD MMM YYYY"}
      onDateChange={handleDateChange}
      closeOnSelect={true}
      published_at="startDate"
      className="form-control text-dark"
     />
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The output is :

[image: output]

Desired Output is :

[image: desired_output]

How can I override the style applied to react-datetime by bootstrap table class ??